# IO Exception Stream Closed using PDFMergerUtility

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish, httpurlconnection, ioexception

collect the inputstream (pdf's) and merge into an single pdf document by using PDFMergerUtility, below are my code (servlet with glassfish server)

```
static HttpsURLConnection connectionGet;
static List<InputStream> sources = new ArrayList<>();
Integer totalPageCount = Integer.parseInt(pageCountValue);
try {
    for (int i = 1; i <= totalPageCount; i++) {
        String inputValue = countryCode + "/" + kindCode;
        String pdfUrl = "abc.org/rest-services/published-data/images/" + inputValue + "/fullimage.pdf?Range=" + i;
        URL pdfDownload = new URL(pdfUrl);
        connectionGet = (HttpsURLConnection) pdfDownload.openConnection();
        String authorizationHeader1 = "Bearer " + getToken;
        connectionGet.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authorizationHeader1);
        connectionGet.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connectionGet.setRequestMethod("GET");
        int pageResponseCode = connectionGet.getResponseCode();
        if (pageResponseCode != 404) {
            sources.add(connectionGet.getInputStream());
        }
    }  
    PDFMergerUtility pdfMerger = new PDFMergerUtility();
    pdfMerger.addSources(sources);
    String pdfFileName = countryCode+kindCode+".pdf";
    String contextPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
    pdfMerger.setDestinationFileName(contextPath+pdfFileName);
    try {                            
        pdfMerger.mergeDocuments();
    } catch (COSVisitorException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(PDFDownloadResult.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    out.println("Document Downloaded Successfully in below server Path" + "<p><b>" +contextPath + pdfFileName+ "</b>");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        } finally {
                // cleanup
                    sources.stream().forEach((source) -> {
                    IOUtils.closeQuietly(source);
                });
        }
    connectionGet.disconnect();
```

Everything works as expected. However when executed a second time I get the following error: Stream closed

```
Severe:   java.io.IOException: stream is closed
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.ensureOpen(HttpURLConnection.java:3295)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3320)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
    at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:139)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.io.PushBackInputStream.read(PushBackInputStream.java:90)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.io.PushBackInputStream.peek(PushBackInputStream.java:68)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.io.PushBackInputStream.isEOF(PushBackInputStream.java:156)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.readLine(BaseParser.java:1517)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parseHeader(PDFParser.java:360)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:186)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1235)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1202)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFMergerUtility.mergeDocuments(PDFMergerUtility.java:235)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFMergerUtility.mergeDocuments(PDFMergerUtility.java:192)
```

Edited: the Problem is `IOUtils.closeQuietly(source);` source value not cleared propelry

Example : exexuted in first time (after deploy) the count will be 2(sources list)  so the document generated without any issues

then i try to run second time , assume current total page count is 3 , now the sources count becomes 5 , this is wrong

so please help me how can clear the `sources` list after the document created

Comment: Execution of second time means running the program second time or calling it as a method for second time during execution?

Comment: @karthi:This is web application execute first time its fine and next time produce strem close exception

Comment: Whether you tried without disconnect () function?

Comment: @Karthi you mean bufferedrader close() / disconnect

Comment: just try by removing this line connectionGet.disconnect();

Comment: @Karthi : problem in sources List(input stream) not cleared properly, updated my question please check

Comment: This is because you need to clear the list after each execution
try this in the final block, sources.clear();

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the list after each iteration add this line in your final block,
`sources.clear();` 
Hope this helps
.